# $x^x-x+5=\frac{29}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form

A friend of mine is claiming to have a closed form solution to $x^x-x+5=\frac{29}{4}$, plotting it into wolfram alpha gives an approximation, and the equation doesn't seem very easy to solve. Can any of you help me finding a solution?

Comment: If wolfram alpha can't find it, the onus of the proof is on him, not you.

Comment: Do you need an exact solution? I don't think you can get one. Try with Newton's method or any other similar algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *A friend of mine is claiming to have a closed form solution to $x^x-x+5=\frac{29}{4}$*

I assume he means the rather obvious $x=-2$.

> *Plotting it into Wolfram Alpha gives an approximation*.

I assume you are referring to the positive transcendental root, somewhere in the vicinity of $2$.

> *Can any of you help me finding a solution?*

I believe we already did. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The equation reduces to $$f(x)=x^x-x-\frac{9}{4}$$ and, by inspection $f(2)=-\frac{1}{4}$ while $f(3)=\frac{87}{4}$. So, as the plot shows it, there is a solution slightly above $x=2$.

A easy procedure to solve nonlinear equation is based on Newton method which, starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, produces the following iteration scheme $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ Using $x_0=2$, the following iterates are generated :$2.04331$, $2.04127$, $2.04126$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

The other solution is "quite" obvious, corresponding to $x=-2$.